# In Kafka, is it possible to read messages which are 1 min old?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I’m trying to work on a usecase which requires the messages to be processed from a kafka topic which are 1 min old.
Is there a way in kafka to only read messages which are 1 minute ild ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you introducing such latency into your processing? If you're waiting for data from other events why not route both through Kafka and use the Kafka Streams API to join both on the relevant key?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. 
Kafka consumers consume based on either getting the Latest message in the queue, or the earliest message.
[See the docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/)
(Search for auto.offset.reset)

I think what you **should** do is hold a buffer of messages in your consuming application. Make your buffer only hold 1 minute's worth of messages and drop messages that are older than 1 minute. That way the oldest message in your buffer is always 1 minute old.

That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to leverage the [reset offset tooling](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-122%3A+Add+Reset+Consumer+Group+Offsets+tooling) introduced in 0.11.0.0. One issue is it is a command line tool and there is no programming API for it (yet). But you might be able to sync your application with the tool (or use the tool inside your application) to reset the offset of a partition to 1 minute ago and consume from there:

```
$ bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --reset-offsets --group test.group --topic foo:0,1 --by-duration P1M
```

This resets the offset of partitions 0 and 1 of topic `foo` to the first message in each partition with timestamp after 1 minute ago. You can check the timestamp of the message to decide whether it qualifies for processing (according to your use case) or not.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to do this using Kafka Streams, state stores and processors. The below solution helps you to process the messages after 1 min, but you will still be consuming the messages immediately.

Create a state store and add it to a stream builder. Create a stream using that builder and add a processor using the above created state store. Use the processor supplier to process each of your messages. You can save all your messages in the state store using process(). Schedule the punctuate() to a 60000 millis and make the punctuate() to get the messages which passed the 1 min delay and process those.

Hope this helps.